# Title Label not showing for UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, uilabel

I am attempting to set a `UIButton` Text through an array like so:

```
// Set User Name
NSString *user = entry[@"user"][@"full_name"];
[cell.nameLabel.titleLabel setText:user];
```

However no text appears on the Application when it loads. The text is being returned and it is stored in the array. Here is my customization of the Button:

```
// Name
self.nameLabel = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(58, 6, 192, 25)];
[self.nameLabel.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Regular" size:12.0]];
self.nameLabel.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(38.0/255.0) green:(120.0/255.0) blue:(172.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.nameLabel];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.nameLabel setTitle:user forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```